# Paypal no BUTTONSOURCE in return URL

Tags: paypal, returnurl

I'm trying to integrate booking system everything was fine in posting and other flow. But after paypal payment page and return to my url BUTTONSOURCE was empty.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include it in both DoExpressCheckoutPayment as well as SetExpressCheckout?
BUTTONSOURCE must be included in both.

Although you'd probably be better off using CUSTOM or INVNUM if you want to use it to link orders on your end together with PayPal transactions.